# Ruby delegating class/relation-level methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

**EDIT** -- *I changed the object-oriented modeling to better reflect the not-particularly-intuitive relationship in my app, (thanks, Anthony) so that this question makes more sense. Sorry about that.*

In my Rails app, I want certain models to be able to delegate to other models on not just an instance level but also a class/relation level. That is to say, assuming a `House` model, which `has_many` `Users` and defines a class-level method "`addresses`" that's called on relations of `houses`, I could do this:

```
users.addresses
```

Behind the scenes, this would actually do two things: 1) run `users.houses` (which would grab all houses with an ID among those plucked from the `house_id` column of the relation of users), and 2) call `addresses` on that relation of houses.

My attempt currently looks something like this:

```
class House
  has_many :users

  def self.addresses
    map(&:address)
  end

  def address
    "#{street_address}, {state}, #{country}"
  end
end

class User

  belongs_to :house

  delegate :address, to: :house

  class << self
    delegate :addresses, to: :houses
  end

  def self.houses
   Houses.where(id: pluck(:house_id))
  end

  ...

end
```

This fundamentally seems to work -- almost. If I have a group of users, I can do `users.houses` and grab the associated relation of `houses`. If I call `addresses` on an unrelated relation of `houses`, the method works great. If I call, `users.addresses`, it calls the class-level method of that name in `houses.rb`.

**But**, the method errors when I try to chain these things together.

If I call `users.addresses` (or `users.houses.addresses`, so delegation isn't the issue here per se), the `House.addresses` method is called, but within that method, `self` seems to be not the **relation** of houses that `users.houses` should (and generally does) return, but just the House class itself. Consequently, if I call any array methods on `self` within `addresses`  (which would work on a relation), the method throws an error such as `undefined method 'map' for <Class:0x1230101239123>`.

This problem persists even if I take away my fancy class-level delegation logic and replace it with the explicit version:

```
class User
  ...
  def self.addresses
    houses.addresses
  end
end
```

Same error. Also when I just try `users.houses.addresses`.

The only version that **does** work is the following:

```
class User
  ...
  def self.addresses
    houses.map(&:address)
  end
end
```

In other words, the logic chain seems to be identical, but moving the `map` into the `User` method and out of the `House` method fixes things.

I'm super confused by this, because to my eyes, that last (successful) version should fundamentally be identical to the two failing versions above. The only difference is that in the successful version, I'm repeating logic in a way I'd like to avoid.

So I guess the questions are

- **1)** Why is `users.houses` returning a relation, but `users.addresses` (and `users.houses.addresses`) suddenly calling `addresses` on the class rather than the relation?
- **2)** Given these issues, is there a better, more Railsy way to set up the relationship between House and User such that I can run these class-level query methods (ie `users.houses`)?

Any opinions on the best way to go about fixing this?

Comment: I don't understand the OO design here.  Wouldn't a household have many users and a user belong to a household?  It seems like that would solve all your problems.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. That was dumb. I have a less self-explanatory data model, and figured it made sense to make up a simpler one to exemplify the issue here -- then I screwed it up. It's basically a has_many and belongs_to. I'll rewrite this question to better reflect my app. But the question still stands (whether or not it really applies to the above) -- are there good ways to delegate relation methods to other relations?