# Active Record querying relation to get other relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to be able to return an AR relation by calling a method on another relation of different model objects. In other words, given a `User` model which `belongs_to` a `House` model (which either `has_one` or `has_many` Users) I want to be able to take a relation of `users` and do `users.houses`, which should return the relation of house objects to which those users belong.

**NOTE** -- I'm not trying to create a `user.houses` method (singular user), but rather a `users.houses` method, which grabs all houses whose ids are among the list of all `house_id`s in the list of `users`. The idea is that this then allows me to call class/relation methods on that relation of houses: `users.houses.house_class_method`.

I've tried doing this "manually":

```
class User
  belongs_to :house

  # Is there some AR Relationship I can declare that would
  # write this method (correctly) for me?
  def self.houses 
    House.where(id: pluck(:house_id))
  end
end
```

House model:

```
class House

  has_many :users

  def self.addresses
   map(&:address) 
  end

  def address
    "#{street_address}, #{city}"
  end
end
```

Two issues, though:

1. This feels (maybe incorrectly) like something that should be
   declarable via a AR relationship.
2. It isn't working correctly. The trouble (as outlined in [this
   separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828821/ruby-delegating-class-relation-level-methods)) is that `users.houses` works fine, but when I
   do `users.houses.addresses`,
   the method is called on the House class, rather than the relation of
   houses that `users.houses` returns (!?!). As a consequence, I get an `undefined method 'map' for <Class:0x1232132131>` error.

Is there a correct way to do this in Rails -- to essentially say that a relation belongs to another relation, or that a model belongs to another, on a relation level as well?

Thanks!

Comment: You want all houses that have a user?  Does it have to be called from user? Or could just make a scope on House? Or do you want to a list of houses that belong to a list of users?

Comment: The last one. List of houses belonging to a list of users. I gave my example version above, but it's not working when I chain methods, ie `list_of_houses_from_list_of_users.array_method` breaks. For more details, check out the other question I linked to.

Comment: What does your house model look like. I am confused about you saying the house has either a has_one or has_many user

Comment: This is a hypothetical model, standing in for less intuitive modeling in my app. I'll give an example above. As in my app, the second model (here `House`) `has_many`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `User` and `House` models might make it easier for accomplishing what you want.

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :houses
  ...
end

class House
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  ...
end

> user = User.find(user_id)
> user.houses # All houses the user  belongs to
> house = House.find(house_id)
> house.users # All users belonging to the house
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not having trouble getting the associations of an individual object. I'm trying to get the association of a full AR relation: so I can call `houses` on `users` (**plural**). In other words, `users.houses` would grab all houses whose ids are in the list generated by `users.pluck(:house_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement `self.houses`; Rails does this for you.

In your User model (`user.rb`), do the following

`def User
  has_many :houses 
  ...
end`

and in your House model

`def House
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end`

from there on, `some_user.houses` returns all the houses that belong to that user. Just make sure there is a user_id (integer) column in your Houses table.

Comment: Thanks, Adib, but, as I make clear in the comment on Prakash's answer above, I want to be able to do `users.houses`, not `user.houses`. The method would effectively do what my `self.houses` method above does (but, correctly). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, `users` would be an `Array` or `ActiveRelation`, not of type `User`

I would recommend a static method on User:

```
def self.houses_for_users(users)
  ..
end
```